# Ways to greet a third person in a conversation?

Tags: greetings

For example a situation where you are on the phone with a friend and he is with a person that you know. You would ask him to say hi for you.

The french equivalent would be "Passer le bonjour"

I am looking for formal and informal ways to say that.

Comment: Zarmad You should clarify your question. The expression "passer le bonjour" means "convey's one's good wishes through one person to another that is not present."

Comment: Formal: *"Give my regards to X"*. Informal *"Say 'Hi' to X [for me]"* or *"Say 'Give X my love"*.

Comment: Edited for clarity!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [most common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=say+hello+to%2Csay+hi+to%2Csay+hey+to%2Csay+howdy+to%2Csay+yo+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csay%20hello%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20hi%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20hey%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csay%20howdy%20to%3B%2Cc0) expression to convey one's good wishes to someone through another is *say hello to someone (from me)*.

Other options (from the least to the most formal one) are:

> *Say hey to someone* (US Regional)
>
> *Say howdy to someone* (US Regional)
>
> *Say hi to someone*
>
> *Give my best to someone*
>
> *Give my love to someone*
>
> *Send/give my greetings to someone*
>
> *Give my regards to someone* (British English)
>
> *Remember me to someone*

[**Passer le bonjour a quelqu'un**](http://french.speak7.com/french_expressions.htm)

Comment: @medica: I don't see that. OP says he is *speaking* to one friend. To me, the logical implication is he means *on the phone*. That's the typical context where the French would say ["Passer le bonjour"](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2209009)

Comment: You're right. I thought it was strange... but I read it literally.

Comment: In British English: "Give my regards to <someone>".

Answer (score 0):

Formally , we just say their name politely and that suffices.
It is considered to be a very dignified gesture to greet someone.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the (admittedly vague) question. OP means contexts like *when you're on the phone to your friend* - so your're not physically present, and can't just say the mutual friend's name and expect it to be heard (unless your first friend is on "speakerphone").

Comment: Oh , the phone thing wasn't mentioned in the question. You can say hey to the person. That will do.

Comment: @VeronicaDiamond Could indeed be the phone thing, but it could also mean "a situation where you're talking with a friend at some place. This friend lives (or is living) with someone you know, and so typically you ask him to say hello to that person from you.